# urxvt misbehaving when set as the default terminal

Tags: command-line, 16.04, update-alternatives

I'm on 16.04 and I've been exploring `urxvt` and it's features and gotten pretty attached to it. I have a simple configuration for now stored in `~/.Xdefaults`. And it works fine whenever I launch it from the `gnome-terminal`. Here's a snap:

[image: urxvt opened with gnome-terminal]

Then I got to setting `urxvt` as my default terminal using `update-alternatives`. I got that done with

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator x-terminal-emulator /usr/bin/urxvt 100
```

I'm not sure if that was right and all (sorry I'm a noob) but anyways, now whenever I launch the terminal(with the keyboard shortcut or by launching `x-terminal-emulator`), it looks like this:
[image: the new urxvt]

It seems like the configurations that I had stored in `~/.Xdefaults` weren't loaded. :(

Any idea how to fix this?

---

**My `~/.Xdefaults` file.**

```
urxvt.font:             xft:Monaco:bold:autohint=true:antialias=true:size=10
Rxvt*font:xft: true
urxvt.scrollBar:        false
urxvt.tintColor:        white

urxvt.pointerColor:     black
urxvt.pointerColor2:    white

URxvt.letterSpace: -1.9

URxvt.geometry: 90x30

*background:  #303030
*foreground:  #dfdebd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm leaving this here in case anyone else had this same problem.
The problem arises because urxvt is launched as a symbolic link(`update-alternatives` operates by symlinking your binaries into `/etc/alternatives`).

So to get around this, I just created a shell script with just

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exec /usr/bin/urxvt $@
```

then saved it as an executable, and set the alternative to that script rather then `/usr/bin/urxvt`.

**Make sure your script is an executable**